# Angular2 - how to trigger event before (click) or (routerLink)

Tags: javascript, angular, events, onclick, onclicklistener

I've created a simple component with template:

```
<div (click)="onClick();">Click me</div>
```

In *.ts file I've got something like that:

```
public onClick() {
    console.log('click');
}

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
public onClickListener(event: Event) {
    console.log('click listener');
}
```

In this case **onClick** function is called always before **onClickListener**.

My goal is to invoke some method before Angular (click) or (routerLink) etc.

It's possible?

What is important - this listener should be a global method, which handle all clicks during runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to invoke before click. Why can it not be handled in the click event?

Comment: I'm sure I understand properly your issue. Why not just do : public onClick() { methodToExecuteBefore();
    console.log('click');
} ?

Comment: Because onClickListener will be in root (main) component finally and must handle all clicks (not only (click)).

Comment: Do you want to handle clicks anywhere in the application, or only on buttons?

Comment: Anywhere. Each click is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle the click events anywhere in the application before they are handled by Angular, you can add a click event listener to the window and specify that the event will be processed in the [capture phase](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing). In the following code snippet, `addEventListener("click", fn, useCapture)` is called with `useCapture` set to true (see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)).

```
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Global click handler");
}, true);
```

You can see it at work in [**this plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/5AQIasQFMr2raIHKLkA0?p=preview).

Comment: very nice implementation

Comment: And that is what I was looking for.